# When does this loop becomes false? division only should cause it

Tags: javascript, loops

Simple code snippet i found, i wanna figure out what stops this loop, is value is true never turns to falls if its just divided by 10?

a number doesn't matter which numbers except 0 always amounts to true, so whats the idea?

Here is the Code:

```js
var value = 2000, sum = 0;

while (value) {
  sum += value % 10;
  value = Math.floor(value / 10);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Why not add a `console.log(value);` inside the loop to check the values to know what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once `value / 10` reaches a value less than 1, `Math.floor` will make the result 0. This will cause the loop to terminate before the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `value` (the while condition) becomes 0, just add a console.log like this to see it:

```js
var value = 2000, sum = 0;

while (value) {
  sum += value % 10;
  value = Math.floor(value / 10);
  console.log('here is  the value ' + value);
}

console.log(sum);
```

What is being returned it's the sum, wich is not the while condition.